# Local-to-global philosophy for crossed modules

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces, crossed-modules

In the survey [Groupoids and crossed objects in algebraic topology](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/hha/1999/0001/0001/HHA-1999-0001-0001-a001.pdf) Ronald Brown made after Corollary 5.17 (p 30) an very interesting remark I not fully understand. He stated that this

> **Corollary 5.17** Let $\mu:M \to P$ be a *crossed module* (Def. p 18), and let $ \iota: P \to Q$ be a morphism of groups. Let $\beta : BP \to B(M \to P) $ ( the latter object is defined on p 20 as *classifying space of a crossed module*) be the inclusion. Consider the pushout

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
BP @>{B \iota}  >> BQ \\
@V{\beta}VV  @VVV  \\
B(M\to P) @>{\beta'}>> X
\end{CD}
$$

> Then the fundamental crossed module of the pair $(X,BQ)$ is isomorphic to the induced crossed module $\iota_∗M \to Q$, and there is a map

$$X \to B(\iota_∗M →Q)$$

> inducing an isomorphism of homotopy groups $\pi_1,\pi_2$.

shows that we have given a local-to-global computation of a homotopy $2$-type.

**Question:** This statement i not understand. In which sense this corollary should be considered as an instance (or say a result in spirit ...) of local-to-global philosophy?

(As far as what I understand under local-to-global principle is than roughly supports the mantra that local computations/ data can be (under reasonable "glueing or compatibility conditions" - say descent in modern terms)  lift to global data)

Comment: I think that is a vague statement. I doubt you’re going to get an answer which can be considered correct or incorrect.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: Yes, indeed it seems that Brown formulated it just on heuristic level, so I agree that there shouldn't expected something precise. But nevertheless, I'm wondering if this provides just on  *intuitive level* how this result at least indicate the "shadow" of certain local-to-global feature in background

Comment: I suppose in the very vaguest sense a pushout might be deemed to be constructed of gluing of "local" data whilst the classifying space (I know its not exactly the same for crossed modules as groups but its the same spirit) is more of a global construction.